# Graph as image in userform not updating

Tags: excel, graph, userform, vba

I have created the following macro, which "prints" two images from two graphs and outputs them in a user form. There are three dropdown bars where you choose a category first, and, then, you choose subcategories (which are then displayed). For some reason, the left image/graph is being updated when I change a category and subcategory. However, when I change the subcategory for the right image/graph, it is not being updated. Ideally, I would like to merge the two images/graphs in one graph for easier comparison. How can I achieve this?

```
    Option Explicit


Private Sub UpdateGraph(rowHeader$, colHeader$, chartName$)
    If rowHeader = "" Or colHeader = "" Then Exit Sub

    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim oFind As Range
    Dim row%, col%
    Dim imgPath$, img As Image

    START

    With shData
        Set oFind = .Range("C:C").Find(rowHeader, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If oFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Header " & rowHeader & " not found in column C", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        row = oFind.row

        Set oFind = .Range("2:2").Find(colHeader, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If oFind Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Header " & colHeader & " not found in row 2", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        col = oFind.Column
    End With

    imgPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "TempChart.gif"

    With shHiddenChart
        .Range("H_ColHeader").Value = colHeader
        .Range("H_" & chartName).Value = rowHeader

        shData.Range(shData.Cells(row, col + 5), shData.Cells(row, col + 20)).Copy
        .ListObjects("tbl" & chartName).DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Set ch = .ChartObjects(chartName).Chart
        ch.Export imgPath, "GIF"
    End With

    Set img = IIf(chartName = "Chart1", imgGraph1, imgGraph2)
    img.Picture = LoadPicture(imgPath)

    On Error Resume Next
    Kill imgPath
    On Error GoTo 0

    FINISH
End Sub

Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub dd1_Change()
    Call UpdateGraph(dd2.Value, dd1.Value, "Chart1")
    Call UpdateGraph(dd3.Value, dd1.Value, "Chart2")
End Sub

Private Sub dd2_Change()
    Call UpdateGraph(dd2.Value, dd1.Value, "Chart1")
End Sub

Private Sub dd3_Change()
    Call UpdateGraph(dd3.Value, dd1.Value, "Chart2")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With shConfig
        Call FillListBox(.ListObjects("tblDD1").DataBodyRange, dd1)
        Call FillListBox(.ListObjects("tblDD2").DataBodyRange, dd2)
        Call FillListBox(.ListObjects("tblDD2").DataBodyRange, dd3)
    End With
End Sub

    Private Sub FillListBox(rng As Range, lBox As ComboBox)
    Dim cell As Range

    lBox.Clear
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        lBox.AddItem cell.Value
    Next
End Sub
```